# Dahon Speed Uno. Main frame hard to fold

Tags: folding-bicycle

Is there a way to lubricate or adjust the tension on the main frame hinge on a Dahon Speed Uno? New bike, and it is extremely difficult to fold in half.

Comment: Since it is new this clearly a case for the dealership to look after.

Comment: I have a non-dahon folder and its tight to fold.  That's because the main pin is critical for the rigidity of the whole bike when you're riding so any sloppiness will result in flex/creaks/wobble while riding.  I'd suggest you check with the dealer if it will bed-in or needs lubrication.

Comment: First I'd have a shot at oiling the hinge.

Answer (score 2):

The main frame hinge is made to have adjustable tension. A little lubrication on moving parts is a good thing.

The manual Dahon publishes is a [one-size-fits-all manual](https://dahon.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/English-Service-Instructions.pdf) with instructions for adjusting a variety of frame hinges starting on page 14.

Here is a [review of the Dahon Speed Uno](https://www.foldingbike20.com/dahon-speed-uno-review/) that goes into great detail on how to operate the bicycle along with videos of folding and unfolding.

Comment: Using an other Dahon bike, I have noticed that more use and more experience does improve folding. (But not fast enough if you really struggle right now.)